# JSP usebean of c:set

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a variable that I set:

```
<c:set var="value" value="<%=bean.getValue() %>"/>
```

where bean is an object that I passed in. Now I want to use this variable, value, as a bean so that I can use it in the `<%=>` tag.

Is there a way of using a varaible set by c:set to use in a `<jsp:useBean>`?

Comment: AFAIK `<jsp:useBean>` and JSTL do not mix (I may be wrong here). Work using scriptlets and `<jsp:useBean>` (ew...) or start working with EL and JSTL (+9001).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com....." scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean>
...
<c:set var="value" value="${bean.value}"/>
```

or did you mean the reverse (from el to jsp:usebean)?

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: just tested (been a while since I've used jsp:useBean) and it's working fine. sample here: [http://pastebin.com/X9YrizHP](http://pastebin.com/X9YrizHP)